# MotionLayout | RecyclerView | Nested Scrolling

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I'm trying to implement a feature using motion layout. In that I have created a motion scene which scrolls from bottom to top and vice versa. After the view goes to the top a recyclerview will be show below to the motion layout.

Issue: While scrolling the recyclerview from top to bottom it's automatically drags the motion scene as well with the velocity applied in the recyclerview. But my objective is to not drag the motion layout as shown in the [attachment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zYveC7ND20g).

Expected behaviour: After the recyclerview's scroll velocity reaches the top. The velocity has to be cancelled. Again, If the recyclerview is scrolled from top to bottom the motion layout should drag to the bottom based on the user's velocity.

[source code](https://github.com/theenathayalan/MotionLayout_RecyclerView)

Comment: Your attachment is now showing.

Comment: kindly check attachment added.

Comment: did you found fix for the issue?